# Swiftui connect command to value in main view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swift5

Does someone know how to connect commands to the rest of the project?
For example: I want to toggle the AddNew variable in the content view to show the add new item sheet by using the command.

```
struct SampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
             CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
                Button("Add new", action: {
                    
                self.AddNew.toggle() // should toggle variable in content View

                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
 @State var AddNew = false
    var body: some View { 

        Button(action: {
            self.AddNew.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Detail")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $AddNew) {
            AddNew(dimiss: $AddNew)
        }

 }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to have a `@Published var` in a class conforming to `ObservableObject`.

You would toggle the boolean *in the class* and access it from wherever you want (as an `@EnvironmentObject` for example).

Like this:

```
class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var addNew: Bool = false

}

struct SampleApp: App {

    @ObservedObject var model = AppModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
        .commands {
             CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
                Button("Add new", action: {
                    self.model.addNew.toggle()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: AppModel

    var body: some View { 

        Button(action: {
            self.model.addNew.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Detail")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $model.addNew) {
            AddNew(dimiss: $model.addNew)
        }

 }
    
}
```

Comment: How would you do this in case `AppModel` can't be shared between multiple scenes? In other words, every ContentView needs to have its own model.